# Name for mappings where there is at least one y for every x

Tags: real-analysis, functions

There are names for several properties of mappings from $x$ in $X$ to $y$ in $Y$. I think we say that a mapping from X to Y is (a)...

- *Function*: there is at most one $y$ for every $x$
- *Injective*: there is at most one $x$ for every $y$
- *Surjective*: there is at least one $x$ for every $y$

How do we say "there is at least one $y$ for every $x$"?

Comment: That just means the domain of the map is $X$, not a subset of it.

Comment: The terminology of [partial functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) may be useful here.

Comment: As stated in an answer, a function means exactly one $y$ for every $x$. What you are describing is simply a relation whose domain is $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relationship from X to Y where every element of X is mapped to an element of Y is called a "Total function".  Relationships where some elements of X are unmapped are called "Partial functions".

However formally all functions are total and people say "Total function" only where it would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

It is typical to define the domain of a function so that every element maps somewhere (a $y$ for every $x$), so there is no special name for it. For example, the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is not properly a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but rather from $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping is the same thing as function.
A function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ corresponds *exactly* one $y\in Y$ for *every* $x\in X$.
But there is also such a thing as set-valued function.
Notice that the sets $X$ and $Y$ are parts of the function $f$ (it's signature).

"At most one" in mathematics means that if there are two elements of something, then they have to be equal. While "at least one" means simply existence.

So, to answer the question, "there is at least one $y$ for every $x$" means there is a set-valued function, mapping each $x\in X$ into a *non-empty set* of $y\in Y$ (a subset of $Y$).
While your definition of a function actually describes a *partial* function (a more complex concept than just a function; as opposed to a "total" function).